# Why In Postman making put request I got validation.required error on all fields filled?

Tags: postman, lumen

In Postman I make put request for lumen 8 app : https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Zag.jpg
and wonder why I got validation.required error  as I filled all fields
under form-data tab? I had to select form-data tab as I need to upload image too...

**MODIFIED :**
In my controller I use PageRequest as :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\Page as PageResource;
use Config;
use App\Http\Requests\PageRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Validator;
use Cloudder;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        \Log::info(  varDump(-321, ' -1 PageController __construct ::') );
    }


    public function store(PageRequest $request)
    {
        // IN THIS VALIDATION/STORING WORKS OK
    } //public function store()

    public function update(PageRequest $request, $id)
    {
        // THIS METHOD IS NOT TRIGGERED
```

and in log file I see empty data sent :

```
[2021-07-12 10:41:43] local.INFO: Array(0) : -1 Controller __construct $this->requestData:: : Array
(
)
  
[2021-07-12 10:41:43] local.INFO: scalar => (integer) : -1 PageController __construct :: : -321
```

Not sure, but I do not see where I set some invalid parameters on POSTMAN or lumen?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the console? just want to make sure the request payload is actually sent.

Comment: What I see in postman's console : https://imgur.com/a/SrjSf8F  Are there some debugging tools which can be used in this case?

Comment: I use the some PageRequest both for store and update methods and it works ok for store method(with valid valiations errors if fields are empty)

Comment: I think nothing wrong with postman, problem might come from your code that handle validation. It's better if you can edit your question, provide code that needed. Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at MODIFIED

Comment: Checking code I do not see any possible reason for this error
Can you advise some tool for requests debuggin?
Seems barryvdh/laravel-debugbar have no such functionality...

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a bug in postman, sending data via form-data with the PUT method always gets a null value, try using raw data json in postman, for more details, maybe go to this link:

https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/630

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).